# Avoid sort warning at the execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following simple query:

```
create table #Table(Id bigint primary key clustered)


insert into #Table (Id)
select  Id
from    dbo.MyTable
where   InsertDate >= '01.04.2016'
        and InsertDate <= '30.04.2016'
option (maxdop 1)
```

But at the execution plan i am always getting a sorting warning, even i don't want to use sort. How can I avoid this (the sorting warring)?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219533/why-is-there-a-sort-showing-up-in-my-execution-plan

Comment: Thanks, i solve my problem 
FYI: option (recompile,maxdop 1)
:):):)

Answer (score 0):

*Why would you want to avoid the sort?*

The query optimiser sees that it is inserting into a table with a **clustered** primary key. In that case, the `SORT` has to happen because that's the way that the data will be physically stored.

As to why there is a warning on the sort, there is a difference between the Estimated Number of Rows and the Actual Number of Rows in your query.
You appear to have an index on `dbo.MyTable` that satisfies your query but there's either a residual predicate or statistical staleness or any number of other potential issues creating this difference between Estimated and Actual Number of Rows.

But in the end we come back to why you want this?